# How can compile a chisel code? Is there any online compiler?

Tags: scala, chisel

How can compile a chisel code? Which apps are you using? I tried to use Scala but, I got errors when I write a chisel code. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Chisel is scala code. You can compile it with a scala compiler -- scalac.

Usually, you use a build tool to do this for you, sbt.

You indicate the toolchain indicates there were errors when compiling your code. This is common. It's virtually unheard of to write code without errors in one go. The error should indicate what you did wrong.